# Why my browser is unable to download files with Rselenium?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

For some reason, I can't download any file using my `Rselenium` and `Firefox` web driver. In short, I'm unable to save the file, the option is greyed out.
I'm using this as a profile:

```
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  browser.download.dir = d_pth,
  browser.download.folderList = 2L,
  browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
  browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force = FALSE,
  browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext"))
```

This is what I get in all the cases, greyed out...

[image]

This is my session info

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.7 readxl_0.1.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3 Rcpp_0.12.7
```

My System Info

```
                              sysname                                       release                                       version                                      nodename                                       machine 
                              "Linux"                            "4.4.0-36-generic" "#55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016"              "wariogs-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC"                                      "x86_64" 
                                login                                          user                                effective_user 
                            "unknown"                                     "wariogs"                                     "wariogs"
```

In addition, I'm running Firefox 48.

Comment: Did you wait for the button to ungrey itself? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/919827

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/1023643/disable-delay-on-download-dialog-buttons

Comment: Yes I waited, and also tried different websites.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with firefox 48 and custom profiles. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2645 There is a suggestion that the next release of geckodriver will fix the issue https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/228 . Maybe you can use Docker and firefox with a custom profile for your task http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I switched to chrome web driver, and its working nice.

Comment: Try including `application/octet-stream` in `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` That will help you